# CCavenue with cordova using angular2 webpack

Tags: cordova, angular, webpack, ccavenue

How to integrate ccavenue in cordova app. I have downloaded website kit from ccavenue site. I have my credentials. Please provide any links or docs.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer my detailed answer on this Medium article — [Integrating CCAvenue in Node.js & Angular 5+ – Meet Dave – Medium](https://medium.com/@daveinside/integrating-ccavenue-in-node-js-angular-5-b9de44091062)

Hope it helps!